# Detecting interfaces and duck typing in Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

There are a couple places in the Closure library where interfaces have an `addImplementation/isImplementedBy` pair of functions to do runtime type checking on the interface (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28080310/20846)).  I'm not entirely a fan of this solution where I have something very simple.  Is there any way to do duck typing with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS enabled?  Say I have an interface, and a component that takes special action on children with that interface, e.g.:

```js
/** @interface */
MyInterface = function() {};

MyInterface.prototype.doSomething = function() {};

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.ui.Component}
 */
MyComponent = function() {
   ...
};

/** @inheritDoc */
MyComponent.prototype.addChild = function(child, opt_render) {
  goog.base(this, 'addChild', child, opt_render);
  if (child.doSomething) {
    child.doSomething();  
  }
};
```

Will ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS consistently rename that "doSomething" property with the implementations?  If not, will adding a type union ensure that it will? e.g.

```js
/**
 * @param {goog.ui.Component|MyInterface} child
 */
MyComponent.prototype.addChild = function( child, opt_render) {
  if (child.doSomething) {
    child.doSomething();  
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `@record` was added for. You'll need to be using a pretty recent version of the compiler to make use of it (something dated at least 2016).

Just replace `@interface` with `@record` and you should get the behavior you desire. The compiler will rename things consistently.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `@record`, it looks very useful, generally. In the case of the type narrowing I'm doing here, I'm not sure if it adds anything - I still want to check for an implicit interface. I realized after the initial post that I can just typecast the variable to the interface and then check for the property - will this only work with `@record` or will it still work with `@interface`?

Comment: An object won't match an interface without an explicit `@implements` annotation on it. It will match a record simply by having a matching signature. You will still need your union type to tell the `addChild` method that the interface can be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

I left Chad's answer as the resolution, but revisited this once I got compilation working and, for the sake of posterity, am posting a more detailed answer for the general case of duck typing.

You can perform dynamic downcasting with ADVANCED optimizations on as follows:

```
var maybeRecordType = /** @type {MyRecordType} */ (someObject);
if ( maybeRecordType.propertyInQuestion ) {
  maybeRecordType.propertyInQuestion();
}
```

You lose compile-time checks this way obviously if there are collisions on the property name between two possible types being passed, but that is always a risk with duck typing.